# A first order theory whose finite models are exactly the $\Bbb F_p$

Tags: logic, field-theory, finite-fields, model-theory, first-order-logic

Is there a first order theory $T$ in the language of rings such that its finite models are exactly the fields $\Bbb F_p$ with $p$ prime (but no $\Bbb F_q$ with $q$ a proper prime power is a model of $T$)?

EDIT: Since this question turned out to be trivial, I asked if it is also possible with a *finite* theory. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425292/a-finite-first-order-theory-whose-finite-models-are-exactly-the-bbb-f-p)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $T$ be the theory of fields with the additional schema:

> If $p\cdot1=0$ then for every $x$ it holds $x=0$ or $x=1$ or $x=1+1$ or ... $x=(p-1)\cdot 1$.

Now if $F$ is a finite model of $T$ then $F$ is a field, and it has exactly the same number of elements as its characteristics.

Note that $F$ is an infinite model of $T$ if and only if it is a field of characteristics zero.

Comment: +1. (Facepalm) Maybe I should have asked after a finite axiomatization...

Comment: @Dominik: I'm not sure that a finite one exists. But I have no idea how to prove that, though.

Comment: Well, *this* theory can't be finitely axiomatized (if it could, then some finite fragment of it would axiomatize it, which is clearly false). I'm not sure how to show there's no finite theory with the same finite models, though.