# A *finite* first order theory whose finite models are exactly the $\Bbb F_p$?

Tags: logic, field-theory, finite-fields, model-theory, first-order-logic

Since [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425275/a-first-order-theory-whose-finite-models-are-exactly-the-bbb-f-p/425280?noredirect=1#425280) question turned out to be trivial, I'm now asking this strengthened version:

Is there a *finitely axiomatized* first order theory $T$ in the language of rings such that its finite models are exactly the fields $\Bbb F_p$ with $p$ prime (but no $\Bbb F_q$ with $q$ a proper prime power is a model of $T$)?

Comment: I don't know anything about model theory, so I could be totally off topic, but I think you can characterize $\mathbb{F}_p$ among the finite fields as the only ones who do not have any non trivial automorphisms.

Comment: @JoelCohen: But that is a second order statement. You are only allowed to quantify over variables, not over functions.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**  This answer is only a proof of a special case of
the given question (the case when the infinite models of the
given theory are exactly the infinite fields).  It does *not*
solve the general question.

**Theorem.**  Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the class of all fields $F$ such
that either $F$ is infinite or $F$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_p$ for 
some prime $p$.  Then $\mathcal{M}$ has no finite FOL-axiomatization.

*Proof.*  For any prime $p$ and any integer $n \geq p$, let
$\sigma_{p,n}$ be the translation of the following statement of
ring theory into a FOL-sentence:

> If $R$ has cardinality $n$ and $p \cdot 1_R = 0_R$, then for
>   every ring element x, x is either $0_R$, $1_R$, $2 \cdot 1_R$, 
>   $\ldots$, or $(p-1) \cdot 1_R$.

Let $\Sigma$ be the union of the first-order field axioms and the
set of all FOL-sentences $\sigma_{p,n}$ for some prime number $p$
and for some integer $n \geq p$.  Then the class of all models of
$\Sigma$ is clearly $\mathcal{M}$.

Suppose now that the class $\mathcal{M}$ has a finite FOL-axiomatization
$\{ \rho_1, \ldots, \rho_m \}$.  Let $\rho$ be the conjunction of
the sentences $\rho_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m$.  Then since $\Sigma$
is also an axiomatization of $\mathcal{M}$, $\rho$ follows logically
from $\Sigma$.  Thus, $\rho$ follows logically from a finite subset
$\Sigma_0$ of $\Sigma$ by the compactness theorem of first-order
logic.  Then $\Sigma_0$ is a finite axiomatization of the class
$\mathcal{M}$.

Since $\Sigma_0$ is finite and there are infinitely many primes,
we can choose a prime $\hat{p}$ and an integer $\hat{n} \geq \hat{p}$
such that for every prime $p \geq \hat{p}$ and for every $n \geq
\hat{n}$, $\sigma_{p,n}$ is not an element of $\Sigma_0$.  Then,
clearly, every field $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ for $p \geq \hat{p}$ and $n
\geq \hat{n}$ is a model of $\Sigma_0$ and must therefore be an
element of $\mathcal{M}$.  But this contradicts our initial assumption
for $\mathcal{M}$.  Therefore $\mathcal{M}$ has no finite
FOL-axiomatization.

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: In order for $\mathcal M$ to be the class of models of $\Sigma$, you need to replace in the description of $\mathcal M$ the clause "$F$ is infinite" with the more restrictive "$F$ has characteristic $0$". (Your result doesn't yet solve the original question, but seems close.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thanks for your hint: I corrected my proof now.

Comment: Can this method be adapted to answer the actual question?

Comment: @ChrisEagle: Where do you see a problem?

Comment: The question isn't about your class $\mathcal{M}$. It just asks whether there's any finite theory whose finite models are the $\Bbb{F}_p$: there's no restriction on what the infinite models are allowed to look like.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: Currently, I am not able to adapt my answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is no. Ax's classical paper *[The Elementary Theory of Finite Fields](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eshmuel/lg-readings/Ax,%20Elementary%20theory%20of%20finite%20fields.pdf)* provides a (nice) algorithm for deciding the set of finite fields satisfying a given statement $E$. A few paragraphs after the statement of the main theorem there is the following remark:

> If $E$ holds for all prime fields, then $E$ holds for all finite fields of sufficiently large characteristic.

which gives a negative answer to your question.